# Is there a way to use a lookup value from a table in a mutate column?

Tags: r, dplyr

```
  library(tidyverse)

df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(Petal.Dim = Petal.Length * Petal.Width,
         rank = rank(desc(Petal.Dim))) %>% 
  mutate(new_col = rank == 4, Sepal.Width)


table <- df %>%
  filter(rank == 4) %>%
  select(Species, new_col = Sepal.Width)

correct_df <- left_join(df, table, by = "Species")

df
#> # A tibble: 150 x 8
#> # Groups:   Species [3]
#>    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species Petal.Dim
#>           <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>
#>  1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa      0.280
#>  2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa      0.280
#>  3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa      0.26 
#>  4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa      0.3  
#>  5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa      0.280
#>  6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa      0.68 
#>  7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa      0.42 
#>  8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa      0.3  
#>  9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa      0.280
#> 10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa      0.15 
#> # ... with 140 more rows, and 2 more variables: rank <dbl>, new_col <lgl>
```

I'm basically looking for `new_col` to show the value that corresponds with rank = 4 from the Sepal.Width column.  In this case, those values would be 3.9, 3.3, and 3.8.  I'm envisioning this similar to a VLookup, or Index/Match in Excel.

Comment: How those values should be distributed for all the rows? You have total 150 rows but only 3 values where `rank == 4` ?

Comment: I want the rank ==4 to fill every row depending on the species matching the ranked value.

Answer (score 0):

When ever I think "now I need to use VLOOKUP like I did in the past in Excel" I find the `left_join()` function helpful.  It's also part of the dplyr package.  Instead of "looking up" values in one table in another table, it's easier for R to just make one bigger table where one table remains unchanged (here the "left" one or the first term you put in the function) and the other is added using a column or columns they have in common as an index.

In your specific example, I can't entirely understand what you want `new_col` to have in it.  If you want to do Excel-style VLOOKUP in R, then `left_join()` is the best starting point.

Comment: @Bhargav I did a left join, but was hoping to find code that was more streamlined.  I added the left join code above.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear since it does not mention the purpose of a Vlookup or Index/Match like operation from Excel.
Also, you don't mention what value should "new_col" have if rank is not equal to 4.
Assuming the value is NA, the below solution with a simple ifelse would work:

```
df <- iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  mutate(Petal.Dim = Petal.Length * Petal.Width,
     rank = rank(desc(Petal.Dim))) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(new_col = ifelse(rank == 4, Sepal.Width,NA))

df
```

[image]